# Add_Image_Size() - Keep asked ratio even if image is smaller

Tags: wordpress

In my current project, I want to have an image that is 1200x600 to fill a 1060x593 space.

Simple enough, I go an do `add_image_size('normalSlider',1200,600,true);` and done right?

But my client uploads an image that is 750x700. So the image that gets put in my slider is 750x600. So instead of having a rectangle, I get a pretty much square, which breaks my slider.

Is there a way in WP to ask, if the image doesn't fill the size, to keep cropping in the right ratio? Like in my exemple, I need an image with the ratio 2:1, and I would like that the cropped image still be a 2:1 ratio. So if my client uploads a 750x700, the crop should be 750x375.

Comment: If you're going to allow images of 750 wide, why not add that as the image size? Otherwise, get your client to upload the right size images.  I know this is easier said than done - but a slideshow normally looks like crap when the images uploaded are too small...

Comment: FYI, this question is an *Exact duplicate* of a question asked on WP StackExchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233065/custom-image-size-thumbnail-crop-to-aspect-ratio-even-when-source-image-is-s

Comment: Yeah I found that one after I asked. And well, I need a 2 for 1 ratio for it to work with my site.

Answer (score 0):

Question has been asked/answered on Wordpress.SE https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165374/how-to-get-post-id-of-static-front-page/165376

The gist of it is you better deal with that on the input, because WP has no way to do it by itself.

Another solution, used in my project, is to watch for the size of the image before using it. If the image doesn't have the right width and height, skip the output of the image.

Couldn't just inform the client about it because it's a site with multiple people coming and modifying contents that will probably not give a damn if they break the site or not. Better make sure some dummy can't break the structure instead of having a site that breaks!